# Use for loop to incrementally select values from MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop

I am trying to use a for loop to select an incremental value with a MySQL query. I have included sample code below:

```
<?php

$day_1="sep_28";
$day_2="sep_29";
$day_3="sep_30";

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = '$id'");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) 
    {
        $dayVar = "day_".$i;
        //$dayVarCount = $dayVar."_count"; // Don't really need this anymore, so removed.
        $dayVarCount = $row[$$dayVar];
        echo "$$dayVar.': '.$dayVarCount<p>"; // Edited.
    }      
}
?>
```

I think I am getting close, but when I run the code my page is showing this:

$day_1.': '.0

$day_2.': '.2

$day_3.': '.5

Any additional recommendations? Thanks for the great help!

Comment: Can you explain a little more?  I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish here.  Running queries in a for loop can be pretty inefficient.  If there's anyway to accomplish it with a single sql query, you will be much better off.

Comment: What exactly do you try to display? Do you want to count the days of the selected month?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a variable variable:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) 
{
    $dayVar = "day_".$i;
    $dayVarCount = $dayVar."_count";
    $$dayVarCount = $row[$$dayVar];
    echo $$dayVar.': '.$$dayVarCount.'<p>'; // Edited.
}
```

This basically uses a string to reference a variable by its name.

Just think of it this way:

```
$variable = 'hello';

$string = 'variable';

echo $$string;
// Is the same thing as:
echo $variable;

// Because you can thing of $$string as ${$string} ---> $variable when {$string} is interpreted into 'variable'
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Comment: Thanks stegrex, I looked at some of the documentation for this and thought it might be the right path, I will try this code out. THANK YOU!

Comment: @Brandon Sure thing, and good luck! You can let me know if it works or not and I can update my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @Stegrex! I have updated the code above, I think I am getting close.

Comment: @Brandon I've made some edits to my answer. Basically, not having the variable variable be interpolated in the double quotes.

Comment: Ive implemented the code and think I am getting closer here, please see above. Also, I added an additional double quote at the beginning of the "echo" line as there wasn't one. THANKS!

Comment: Hi @Stegrex, do you know how I would call one of these values outside of the for loop? for example, if i wanted to call the value of $day_3_count, how would I do that? Do I need to open a new question for this?

Comment: @Brandon I've made a couple more edits. Actually, my code had an ending double quote but the syntax was wrong. You don't need to wrap the variable variables in double quotes. Also, if you change loop to what I have now, you should be able to call the value of $day_3_count outside the loop just by doing `echo $day_3_count;` This is due to the value loaded into the variable variable $$dayVarCount when $i is equal to 3.

Answer (score 1):

Replace this line:

```
echo "$$dayVar.': '.$dayVarCount<p>";
```

with this:

```
echo $$dayVar . ': ' . $dayVarCount . '<br>';
```

Comment: Yep, @Stegrex had given me all that code, but your adjustment made it all click. Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad to hear that, yes @Stegrex solution is fitting I guess. I upvote that! :D

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$day_1="January 1";
$day_2="January 2";
$day_3="January 3";

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM dates WHERE id = '$id'");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) 
    {
        $var = $."day_".$i;
        $day_$i_count=$row['$var'];
        echo "$day_$i: $day_$i_count<p>";
    }       
}
?>
```

You can try this code too.

Answer (score 0):

That all seems overly complicated, but possibly I don't understand the question adequately.  Would this work?

```
$day[1]="sep_28";
$day[2]="sep_29";
$day[3]="sep_30";

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = '$id'");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
    foreach ($day as $day_str) 
    {
        echo $day_str . ':' . $row[$day_str] . '<p>';
    }      
}
```